# Convert string to bytes32

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to convert `string` to `bytes32`?

For example:

```
contract c {  
    string public name;  
    mapping (string => bytes32) str2bytes32;  

    function test(string t) returns(bytes32){  
        name = t;  
        return str2bytes32[name];  
    }  
}
```

Upon deploying this contract and calling the function test always returns `0x`, no matter what string I pass in. So just wondering what the issue is. However, changing the argument type from `string` to `bytes32` in the function and changing the variable type for name helped ensuring the return value of `bytes32`. Any suggestions as to why the hash map didn't work would be helpful?

Comment: check the answer in : [http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytes32](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytes32)