# How to convert a string to bytes32?

Tags: solidity, string, bytes32

How can I convert a `string` to a `bytes32`?
Does anyone has a magic function or library which does it?

For example, this will works since as input I gave `bytes32` . But it does not work with the characters greater than `bytes32`.

```
tx_hash = a.transact().set("QmVoGzRDscx61k3RHHkLYaMFtxYZi3ps") // 32-bit char
```

---

```
function get() returns (string value) {  
    return list.get_head_data();   
}
```

But if I need to give more character for example contains 48-bit string this won't work. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This has worked for me so far. Not sure if it's the best way.

```
function stringToBytes32(string memory source) public pure returns (bytes32 result) {
    bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
    if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }

    assembly {
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
    }
}
```

Also, remember that strings in solidity are UTF8 so after converting them to bytes each byte is not necessarily a character.

EDIT: shorter version, should work the same.

Comment: xpected elementary inline assembly operation.
                 bytes32 result := mload(add(source, 32))
                 ^
           contracts/Link.sol:77:22: Error: Expected token Semicolon got 'Colon'
                 bytes32 result := mload(add(source, 32))

Comment: @Avatar you have `bytes32 result :=` while my code is declaring result type in `returns (bytes32 result)`, just remove the `bytes32` from before `result := ...` and it should compile.

Comment: awesome works!! Thank you sir. One final question is, if my string is larger than 32 bits such as 48 bits the remaining 12 bits will be trimmed. 
Would there be additional assemble line that I can obtain bits from 32 to 48?
thank you for your valuable time.
when I did "result := mload(add(source, 64)) " it worked!

Comment: I tried your code in remix.ethereum.org (using JavaScript VM) and entered "EOS8WE79SonHGHc5DquV4fxty9bHfnLSugCyTVXj2n9t4Uw5HL2vU" as my string, which is 56 characters long.  It returned: "0x454f533857453739536f6e4847486335447175563466787479396248666e4c53" When I convert this into ASCII, I get "EOS8WE79SonHGHc5DquV4fxty9bHfnLS", which is 34 characters.  Why?  How do I get the original 56 characters back?

Comment: @Curt you can't, conversion from string to bytes32 is lossy. bytes32 can contain only 32 8-bit characters but strings can be longer than 32 characters and during this operation all characters above 32 are lost.
The string you pasted has 32 characters, I didn't count the quotation characters.

Comment: Also, this function should probably be marked "internal" to save some gas

Comment: Took me a while to figure out so for the interested: AFAIK 'source' within assembly in this context refers to the memory address of source not the string it points to. Then we add 32 to this address as the first 32 bytes are seemingly reserved to hold the number of chars in the string (/length of the array).

Comment: Could you guys explain why this code works? What's the significance of adding 32 to the string's memory address pointer, and how does this convert it to bytes32?

Answer (score 23):

`string` is not equal to `bytes32` but it is equal to `bytes`, because its length is dynamic.

so you could use a casting `bytes B=bytes(S); //S string`

E.g

```
contract string_test {

    function string_tobytes( string s) constant returns (bytes){
        bytes memory b3 = bytes(s);
        return b3;
    }
}
```

The conversion of `string` to `bytes32` is possible only using assembly

Comment: Error: Explicit type conversion not allowed.
          bytes b = bytes("a");

Comment: try the new code above using memory variable.

Comment: TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "literal_string "mined"" to "bytes storage pointer".

`bytes memory data = bytes("mined");`

Answer (score 22):

ethers.js has a built in utility function for this: https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-utils.html#bytes32-strings

```
const ethers = require('ethers')
const utils = ethers.utils

const inBytes = utils.formatBytes32String("test");
```

Comment: This should be the right solution gentlemen

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which was about how to do this inside a smart contract, not how to do it javascript.

Comment: @GGizmos perhaps but it's what I was also looking for and search brought me here

Answer (score 8):

Assembly is not needed in version 0.8.7

```
string text = "whatever"; 
bytes32 stringInBytes32 = bytes32(bytes(text));
```

Comment: I tried this, what I want to do is send a bytes32 string to solidity and store it in a bytes32 variable.  If I take the input string:  '0x41b1a0649752af1b28b3dc29a1556eee781e4a4c3a1f7f53f90fa834de098c4d' and follow your code (bytes32(bytes(inputstring) I get '0x3078343162316130363439373532616631623238623364633239613135353665' from console.logBytes32 inside the solidity function.  Seems to be all integers, altho the right length.  Any ideas why that is:

Comment: @GGizmos, **text** is supposed to be a string of UTF-8 characters. You are using an hexadecimal value, I don't how to do it in that case.

Comment: When I try this I get Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes memory" to "bytes32". using a string from a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
contract stringtobytes{
    function set(string memory  _a)public pure returns(bytes memory){
        return (bytes(_a));
    } 
}
```

you  can  convert strings to bytes(in decimal format) with below code

1- bytes1=8bit=2decimal

2  bytes2=16bit=4decimal

3  bytes3=24bit=6decimal

4  bytes=dynamic array and reference value

Comment: The question was about converting from string to bytes32, your example doesn't work for bytes32.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get(string memory key) 
    public 
    view 
    returns (bytes32) {
        return bytes32(abi.encodePacked(key));
}
```

Comment: I get - Explicit type conversion not allowed from "bytes memory" to "bytes32".

Comment: @NickJ The answer is correct. Check your code.

Answer (score -1):

Please reference this. You can convert string to bytes32 array.The length of string can be longer than 32 .

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/13388/6353