# Convert 'bytes memory' to 'bytes8'

Tags: solidity, memory, bytes

In solidity, how can I convert bytes memory buffer to bytes8 type?
Example:

`bytes8 buf2 = bytes8(memory_buf); // TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using assembly it could look like this (copied and edited from [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytes32/9152#9152)):

```
function convertBytesToBytes8(bytes inBytes) returns (bytes8 outBytes8) {
    if (inBytes.length == 0) {
        return 0x0;
    }

    assembly {
        outBytes8 := mload(add(inBytes, 32))
    }
}
```

This is an older inefficient suggestion without using assembly, probably don't use this:

```
function convertBytesToBytes8(bytes inBytes) returns (bytes8 outBytes8) {
    uint256 maxByteAvailable = inBytes.length < 8 ? inBytes.length : 8;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < maxByteAvailable; i++) {
        bytes8 tempBytes8 = inBytes[i];
        tempBytes8 = tempBytes8 >> (8 * i);
        outBytes8 = outBytes8 | tempBytes8;
    }
}
```

Basically it iterates over each of the first 8 bytes in the `inBytes` array, converts it to a `bytes8` variable, then shifts this variable to the right by an appropriate amount, then OR's the variable with the current result (which basically appends it, since the default value for the `outBytes8` is all zeros).

I haven't tested either extensively but they seem to work.

Comment: I dont think it will work much faster with assembly. By the way, it solved my problem.

Comment: Check the above edit with the assembly version, I'm sure it's more efficient.

Comment: The original example converted to bytes32. In this case for a byte8, I think you should expect ``outBytes8 := mload(add(inBytes, 8))``

Comment: For converting to bytes4, I just changed the function signature to `function convertBytesToBytes4() public returns (bytes4 outBytes8)` and it seems to work but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This function bytesc8  and try the solidity this :

```
 function getHexString(bytes4 value) pure public returns (string) {
        bytes memory result = new bytes(8);
        string memory characterString = "0123456789abcdef";
        bytes memory characters = bytes(characterString);
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            result[i * 2] = characters[uint256((value[i] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
            result[i * 2 + 1] = characters[uint256(value[i] & 0xF)];
        }
        return string(result);
    }
```

Please try it

Thank You