# Where can I find a string to bytes32 converter online?

Tags: solidity, string, bytes32

So far I am using [this solidity code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9152/39171)

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract Converter{
    function Converter(){

    }

    function stringToBytes32(string memory source) returns (bytes32 result) {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }

        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a website or online tool to easily convert strings to bytes32?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have MetaMask installed, then the following works in the browser console:

```
> web3.padRight(web3.fromAscii('hello'), 34)
"0x68656c6c6f0000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. From the [official Metamask docs](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3):

For historical reasons, MetaMask injected web3@0.20.7 is deprecated. It has known security issues. It is no longer maintained by the web3.js team.

Answer (score 4):

Online GUI here for converting bytes32 to string and the other way: https://blockchangers.github.io/solidity-converter-online/

Answer (score 0):

[Cindercloud](https://cinder.cloud/tools/convert-string-to-bytes32) also had an online converter, as well as some other useful tools for interacting with ethereum and other chains.

Answer (score 0):

Another online GUI:

Convert from a bytes32/hex into a string/number or vice-versa.

https://web3-type-converter.onbrn.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bytes32` library from npm
https://npm.devtool.tech/bytes32

`$ npm install bytes32`

`$ npx bytes32`
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

`$ npx string`
0x737472696e670000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

I made an online utility for via versa conversion of String to Bytes32. It is client side also, so everything runs on the browser.

[Online String to Bytes32 Converter](https://www.devoven.com/string-to-bytes32)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web3 tools created by Neptune Mutual which has `String to Bytes32 Converter` and vice versa.

https://neptunemutual.com/web3-tools/