# Is it possible to deploy a contract using create2 in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, solidity-0.6.x, create2

Can I deploy a contract in Solidity (not in-line assembly) using `create2`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. [Solidity version 0.6.2](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.6.2) introduced a high-level way to use the `create2` opcode. From the release docs:

> When creating a contract, you can specify the salt as a "function call option": `new Contract{salt: 0x1234}(arg1, arg2)`

As an example, the following `deploy()` function will deploy the `Test` contract using a `salt` of `0x1234` and a constructor param of `123`.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.2;

contract Test {
    uint256 public a;
    constructor (uint256 _a) public {
        a = _a;
    }
}

contract DeployTest {
    function deploy() public {
        new Test{salt: 0x1234}(123);
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** `salt` has to be `bytes32`. See here: [How to convert a string to bytes32?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/how-to-convert-a-string-to-bytes32)

For example: `ethers.utils.formatBytes32String("test");` ➡️ `0x7465737400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `Solidity version 0.6.2` you can do it